# Function digits(n) that returns how many digits the number has , returns a random value in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, count, return

The function digits, in the while loop - while (n > 0) returns 325 326 327 and 1 as the count value and if I use while (n > 1) it returns the correct number count. Any logical reason for this behavior?

```
def digits(n):
    count = 0
    if n == 0:
      return 1
    while (n > 0):
        count += 1
        n = n / 10
    return count
    
print(digits(25))   # Should print 2
print(digits(144))  # Should print 3
print(digits(1000)) # Should print 4
print(digits(0))    # Should print 1
```

Comment: Maybe you mean ```n = n // 10```? There is a difference between ```/``` normal division and ```//``` floor division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `/` and `//`.

`/` does the normal division given an accurate answer upto 15 decimal places in python. However, `//` is the floor division method where only the quotient of the division is returned.

try to replace:

```
n = n / 10
```

with this:

```
n = n // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

**Correct Code**

```
def digits(n):
    count = 0
    if n == 0:
      return 1
        while (n > 0):
            count += 1
            n = n//10
        return count
        
    print(digits(25))   # Should print 2
    print(digits(144))  # Should print 3
    print(digits(1000)) # Should print 4
    print(digits(0))    # Should print 1
```

**Logic being used**
We're using floor division instead of normal one because normal one will make the loop take very much time but return nothing so here,
we'll use floor division until n gets smaller than 10 till then the count will get increasing by 1

For ex: We take 25 as an input

- 25 // 10 = 2        *count gets 1*
- 2 // 10 = inputs gets smaller than zero     *count increases by 1
  until condition is satisfied so now the count is 2*

*Hope this helps :)*

Answer (score 0):

If you divide something by 10 it will always be larger than 0, a quicker way would be:

```
def digits(n):
    return len(str(n))
```